# Any *real* useful usage for the "clear key" on apple wired keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, ui

I work on Macs for over two years and still haven't done anything useful with the "clear key" ([this one](http://kb.parallels.com/Attachments/4815/Images/apkb.jpg)).

Do you know of any useful stuff it can do? Other than with the built-in Calculator app, that one doesn't count :)

EDIT:
Anything you use on regular bases.